# É viável colocar um IdHTTPServer num Aplicativo móvel para que ele receba mensagens instantâneas de um servidor remoto?

Tags: delphi, http, cliente-servidor, firemonkey

Pretendo fazer um aplicativo que receba notificações sem ficar consultando o servidor a todo momento, e que seja capaz de rodar em background no Android. Irei usar a plataforma Firemoney, que usa object pascal para substituir java. Usarei a biblioteca Indy para as implementações cliente/servidor.

Com a utilização de UDP aparecem as barreiras do NAT e Firewall, tanto em WAN quanto em LAN, ou seja, seja no WiFi ou no 3G/4G terei problemas.

Mas e se eu, ao iniciar a aplicação, enviar uma requisição para o servidor para que ele anote o IP e relacione o mesmo ao login do usuário, será que seria interessante e viável eu utilizar uma requisição HTTP do servidor para o aplicativo, usando esse IP cadastrado toda vez que precisasse avisá-lo de alguma coisa?

Pelo que sei as requisições HTTP são mais fáceis de passar por roteadores, firewalls e NAT... Ainda não fiz um teste em código pois queria saber se alguém aqui já tentou ou ficou sabendo de algum resultado, positivo ou negativo.

Answer (score 0):

Porque você não usa a tecnologia **DataSnap** para comunicação entre cliente/servidor, você pode fazer transações via *JSON* que é muito mais rápido, mas existem algumas particularidades quanto a tecnologia, depende de como você vai querer trabalhar, com *sessão*, *invocation* ou *server*.

**Server:** O servidor mantém uma única instância da classe no server, todos os clientes ao solicitar essa classe receberão sempre a mesma instância.

**Session:** O servidor mantém uma instância da classe por sessão do DataSnap, cada cliente recebe uma instância diferente da classe.

**Invocation:** A cada execução de um server method uma instância da classe será criada e logo depois destruída.

E a própria tecnologia DataSnap desconecta depois de ter feito uma requisição para o servidor.

Comment: Porque só funciona se o servidor for Windows.

Comment: Por curiosidade, porque você quer fazer do aplicativo um servidor?... e o cliente fica encarregado de mandar mensagens para o aplicativo?... não seria ao contrario.

Comment: Só se o que você quer, é um serviço no aplicativo que fique monitorando mensagens novas no servidor remoto.